# Show and hide div using JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/AjAw9/1/)

```
        $szPostContent = $post->post_content;
        $szSearchPattern = '#(<img.*?>)#';
        $a='';
        $aPics='';
        preg_match_all( $szSearchPattern, $szPostContent, $aPics );
        $iNumberOfPics = count($aPics);
        echo "<br />Number of pics on each post...............".$iNumberOfPics;
        array_push($postimg, $iNumberOfPics);
```

$iNumberofPics shows image from single post...
look at the demo ..u will find that on mouseover of arrow imgthe slider dissapears.while i want to show that main div continously until the users remains there on that page..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AjAw9/5/

Comment: @Spokey -- Thanks for reply but i wanted to show that imageslider div and also two arrow classes and on mouseout of imageslider div i want to hide that imageslider div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class='container' style='height:150px; width:225px;'>
    <div class="imageslider" id="imageslider" style="border: 1px solid #000000; height:150px; width:225px;display:none">
        <img class="arrow left" style="border: 1px solid #000000; height:25px; width:25px; float:left; margin-top:50px;" />
        <div class="images"></div>
        <img class="arrow right" style="border: 1px solid #000000; height:25px; width:25px; float:right; margin-top:50px;" />
    </div>
```

And Script

```
$(".container").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.imageslider').show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.imageslider').hide();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AjAw9/7/)

`.container` is there as a placeholder in order for you to be able to mouse it over and out

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got your question right, so I hope one of these approaches help you:
In your code you use onmouseout, not onmouseover. You can:

- Use $(...).show()  and $(...).hide() on mouseover and mouseout.
- Take a look at $(...).toggle() that will take away some work.